# Don't get value for variable out of function

Tags: c, variables, trigonometry

i have to creat a C program to calculate the hight of a objekt with the input of alpha, beta and the length between them.

I think my program is working well, i also have a function to calculate deg in rad for sinus function.

I need the output for corner phi in my main function. When I try to printf phi in my double h() function i get the value for phi, but the value dont come to my main function.

I hope you can help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double bogen(double x){         /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/
double rad;

rad = (M_PI/180) * x;

return rad;         /*Return Wert in Radius*/
}


double phiWinkel(double a, double b){           /*Funktion für Berechnung Winkel phi*/
double phi;

phi = b - a;

return phi;                 /*Return Wert für h()*/
}

double uLaenge(double a, double p, double s){       /*Funktion für Berechnung u Länge*/
double u;

a = bogen(a);                   /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/
p = bogen(p);                   /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/

u = s * sin(a) / sin(p);

return u;                   /*Return Wert für h()*/
}

double h(double a, double b, double p, double s){   /*Funktion für Berechnung der Höhe*/
double h;
double u;

p = phiWinkel(a, b);                /*Aufruf Phi Funktion mit Parameter*/

u = uLaenge(a, p, s);               /*Aufruf u Funktion mit Parameter*/

b = bogen(b);                   /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/

h = u * sin(b);                 /*Berechnung Höhe*/

return h;                   /*Return Wert für main()*/
}

int main(){
double alpha;                   /*Initialisierung der Variablen*/
double beta;
double phi;
double strecke;
double hoehe;

printf("\n\n\t\t+++ Landvermessung - Höhenbestimmung +++\n");               /*Einleitung in das Programm mit Aufforderung zur Nutzereingabe*/
printf("\n\t+++ Dieses Programm berechnet die Höhe eines Objektes +++");
printf("\n+++ Benötigt werden Werte für Strecke zwischen den Winkeln, alpha und beta in Grad +++");
printf("\n\t+++ Bestätigen Sie Ihre Eingabe mit der Eingabe-Taste +++\n");
printf("\nBitte geben Sie den Wert für die Strecke - s - ein: ");
scanf("%lf", &strecke);
printf("\nBitte geben Sie den Wert für den Winkel Alpha - a - ein: ");
scanf("%lf", &alpha);
printf("\nBitte geben Sie den Wert für den Winkel Beta - b - ein: ");
scanf("%lf", &beta);


hoehe = h(alpha, beta, phi, strecke);                   /*Aufruf h() mit Parameter*/

printf("\nDer Turm hat eine Höhe von:\t%.2lf Metern.\n", hoehe);    /*Ausgabe*/
printf("Die Strecke - s - beträgt:\t%.2lf Meter.\n", strecke);
printf("Der Winkel alpha beträgt:\t%.2lf Grad.\n", alpha);
printf("Der Winkel beta beträgt:\t%.2lf Grad.\n", beta);
printf("Der Winkel phi beträgt:\t\t%.2lf Grad.\n", phi);

return 0;
}
```

Big Thanks to Liamcomp.
This is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double bogen(double x){         /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/
    double rad;

    rad = (M_PI/180) * x;

    return rad;         /*Return Wert in Radius*/
}

double winkel(double rad){
    double x;

    x = (rad/M_PI)*180;

    return x;
}

double phiWinkel(double a, double b){           /*Funktion für Berechnung Winkel phi*/
    double phi;
    double tmp;                 /*Zwischenspeicher für if*/

    if(a > b){                  /*Falls alpha größer als beta um negativ Wert zu verhindern*/
        tmp = b;
        b = a;
        a = tmp;    

    }

    phi = b - a;

    return phi;                 /*Return Wert für h()*/
}

double uLaenge(double a, double p, double s){       /*Funktion für Berechnung u Länge*/
    double u;

    a = bogen(a);                   /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/
    p = bogen(p);                   /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/

    u = s * sin(a) / sin(p);

    return u;                   /*Return Wert für h()*/
}

double h(double *a, double *b, double *p, double *s){   /*Funktion für Berechnung der Höhe*/
    double h;
    double u;

    *p = phiWinkel(*a, *b);             /*Aufruf Phi Funktion mit Parameter*/

    u = uLaenge(*a, *p, *s);                /*Aufruf u Funktion mit Parameter*/

    *b = bogen(*b);                 /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/

    h = u * sin(*b);                    /*Berechnung Höhe*/

    *b = winkel(*b);                /*Rückrechnung Bogenmaß in Winkelmaß*/

    return h;                   /*Return Wert für main()*/
}

int main(){
    double alpha;                   /*Initialisierung der Variablen*/
    double beta;
    double phi;
    double strecke;
    double hoehe;

    printf("\n\n\t\t+++ Landvermessung - Höhenbestimmung +++\n");               /*Einleitung in das Programm mit Aufforderung zur Nutzereingabe*/
    printf("\n\t+++ Dieses Programm berechnet die Höhe eines Objektes +++");
    printf("\n+++ Benötigt werden Werte für Strecke zwischen den Winkeln, alpha und beta in Grad +++");
    printf("\n\t+++ Bestätigen Sie Ihre Eingabe mit der Eingabe-Taste +++\n");
    printf("\nBitte geben Sie den Wert für die Strecke - s - ein: ");
    scanf("%lf", &strecke);
    printf("\nBitte geben Sie den Wert für den Winkel Alpha - a - ein: ");
    scanf("%lf", &alpha);
    printf("\nBitte geben Sie den Wert für den Winkel Beta - b - ein: ");
    scanf("%lf", &beta);


    hoehe = h(&alpha, &beta, &phi, &strecke);                   /*Aufruf h() mit Parameter*/

    printf("\nDer Turm hat eine Höhe von:\t%.2lf Metern.\n", hoehe);    /*Ausgabe*/
    printf("Die Strecke - s - beträgt:\t%.2lf Meter.\n", strecke);
    printf("Der Winkel alpha beträgt:\t%.2lf Grad.\n", alpha);
    printf("Der Winkel beta beträgt:\t%.2lf Grad.\n", beta);
    printf("Der Winkel phi beträgt:\t\t%.2lf Grad.\n", phi);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code here, a picture is no good. You should be able to paste your code, highlight it and press the code sample button which looks like `{}`

Comment: @liamcomp I tried it, but the editor aborts the code several times

Comment: @liamcomp Now i get it. I have to put some spaces in the code.

Comment: Great. I've added some comments as an answer

Comment: Do you mind improving the formatting? It's fairly hard to read.

Comment: normaly my code is well formated. But when i paste it my format is gone. But i have a solution now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass values by reference (passing pointers) then you get any modifications of the value back to `main`, for example, declare `h` like so:

```
double h(double* a, double* b, double* p, double* s)
```

You may not need to pass all values as pointers.

In `h` you would then need to dereference these variables with a *, for example:

```
    *p = phiWinkel(a, b);
```

And in `main` you would call by passing a pointer with &:

```
hoehe = h(&alpha, &beta, &phi, &strecke);
```

You may not need to pass all values by reference but you'll be able to judge whether it is required. If you only need to pass `p` by reference then your `h` function should look like this:

```
double h(double a, double b, double* p, double s) {   /*Funktion für Berechnung der Höhe*/
    double h;
    double u;

    *p = phiWinkel(a, b);                /*Aufruf Phi Funktion mit Parameter*/

    u = uLaenge(a, *p, s);               /*Aufruf u Funktion mit Parameter*/

    b = bogen(b);                   /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/

    h = u * sin(b);                 /*Berechnung Höhe*/

    return h;                   /*Return Wert für main()*/
}
```

with call

```
hoehe = h(alpha, beta, &phi, strecke);
```

And finally, if you wanted to avoid the use of pointers, then you could calculate `p=phiWinkel(a, b);` in `main` instead of doing it in `h` and simply pass `p` as a value to `h` just like before.

Comment: Now i have errors 

with double h(double& a, double& b, double& p, double& s)
u03b_Funktionen_Trigonometrie_Leuchtturm.c: In function ‘main’:
u03b_Funktionen_Trigonometrie_Leuchtturm.c:69:10: error: expected expression before ‘double’
  hoehe = double h(double& alpha,double& beta,double& phi,double& strecke);

with h(double& a, double& b, double& p, double& s)
u03b_Funktionen_Trigonometrie_Leuchtturm.c: In function ‘main’:
u03b_Funktionen_Trigonometrie_Leuchtturm.c:69:12: error: expected expression before ‘double’
  hoehe = h(double& alpha,double& beta,double& phi,double& strecke);

Comment: @Kevin Oops. Overlooked that we are talking C. Have edited the answer.

Comment: @J.R. I dont learn how to use pointers or arrays. I think this comes in the next lessons in school. You know a way without pointer?

I tried this and is dont working. I put * to p = phiWinkel(a,b); and & to phi in h(alpha, beta, &phi, strecke)


u03b_Funktionen_Trigonometrie_Leuchtturm.c:39:2: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)
  *p = phiWinkel(a, b);  

u03b_Funktionen_Trigonometrie_Leuchtturm.c: In function ‘main’:
u03b_Funktionen_Trigonometrie_Leuchtturm.c:69:25: error: incompatible type for argument 3 of ‘h’
  hoehe = h(alpha, beta, &phi, strecke);

Comment: @SefaSimsek I have added additional detail. Note the additional dereferencing of `p` in the calculation of `u`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it like liamcomp have done it. This works very well.

Comment: Because of your Feedback to calculate p in main. - Yes this would be easier. But the professor wants only h function in main and every calculation have to be done in function h

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an argument to a function in C, the argument is copied so if you change the argument in the function the argument will indeed not be changed after you return from the function. If you pass the address of something then the function can change it.

So you would need to change `h`:

```
double h(double *a, double *b, double *p, double *s);
```

And now you have the addresses, when you want to access the data at `a` you will need to use `*a`

So your function could look like this now:

```
double h(double *a, double *b, double *p, double *s){   /*Funktion für Berechnung der Höhe*/
    double h;
    double u;

    *p = phiWinkel(*a, *b);                /*Aufruf Phi Funktion mit Parameter*/

    u = uLaenge(*a, *p, *s);               /*Aufruf u Funktion mit Parameter*/

    *b = bogen(*b);                   /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/

    h = u * sin(*b);                 /*Berechnung Höhe*/

    return h;                   /*Return Wert für main()*/
}
```

And you would call it by passing the addressed like this:

```
hoehe = h(&alpha, &beta, &phi, &strecke);
```

If you don't want to use pointers then you could get rid of the `h` function and do:

```
double h;
double u;

p = phiWinkel(a, b);                /*Aufruf Phi Funktion mit Parameter*/

u = uLaenge(a, p, s);               /*Aufruf u Funktion mit Parameter*/

b = bogen(b);                   /*Umrechnung Winkelmaß in Bogenmaß*/

h = u * sin(b);                 /*Berechnung Höhe*/
```

Directly in `main`

Comment: Thank you. I think this worked. Now I get phi in my printf. 

I dont understand what you explained me and what i have done but it works. :D 

I only have to turn my beta back from rad to deg an then i think im finish.

Thank you very much.

PS: I will learn arrays and pointers asap

Comment: Happy to help. Hopefully you will gain an understanding of pointers in the near future.